# Adding Google Play APK Expansion Library package causes "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

Tags: android, apk

I am STILL trying to follow the documentation for using "APK Expansion Files" (http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Preparing).  When I get to part where I add the "downloader_library" project to my App's project all tokens of the form `R.` become unresolved.
I also notice that my project does not generate a `gen/R.java` for my App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have given up using eclipse in favor on command line development on Ubuntu for Android. These problem do not happen with `ant`.